# WCF metedata download troubles

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, iis, svcutil.exe

I am having the following error creating the WCF Client Library for my application using the svcutil tool. I can do the same operation successfully on my local machine but not on the server with IIS.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>svcutil.exe
>   http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie/beanie.svc?wsdl Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool [Microsoft (R)
>   Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.33440]
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Attempting to download metadata from
>   'http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/
>   beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?wsdl' using
>   WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO. Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata
>   Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version
>   4.0.30319.33440] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?wsdl
>
> If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have acce ss, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing
>   at the specified addr ess.  For help enabling metadata publishing,
>   please refer to the MSDN documentat ion at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>
> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?wsdl
>
> ```
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://beanie
> ```
>
> .elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?ws
>   dl'.
>
> ```
> Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by servic e
> ```
>
> http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?wsdl.  The client and service bindings may be
>   mismatched.
>
> ```
> The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message becaus e the content type 'application/soap+xml;
> ```
>
> charset=utf-8' was not the expected ty pe 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>
> HTTP GET Error
>       URI: http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie_deploy
>   loy/beanie.svc?wsdl
>
> ```
> The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
> ```
>
> - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>     - There was an error downloading 'http:// win-iu76ruu909k /beanie_deploy/beanie.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
>     - The remote name could not be resolved: 'win-iu76ruu909k'
>
> If you would like more help, type "svcutil /?"

What can I do to get started with fixing them?

> EDIT:web.config file
>
> ```
> <behaviors>
>   <serviceBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
>       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
>     </behavior>
>   </serviceBehaviors>
> </behaviors>
>
> <services>
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="Syncre_LayerAB_WebService.LayerAB_WebService">
>     <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
>         bindingConfiguration="" contract="Syncre_LayerAB_WebService.ILayerAB_WebService" />
>   </service>
> </services>
> ```

Comment: Without the <system.serviceModel> node from the WCF service on your server it is hard to figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: thanks, I just made the edit

Answer (score 1):

Your service is correctly configured to publish its metadata, but I suspect the problem lies with the IIS settings.  For example, security could be configured to use Ntlm or Basic authentication while your service is using Anonymous access.

That "charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml'" error indicates that IIS is returning an error message instead of the metadata.  Try to open the svc url (http://beanie.elasticbeanstalk.com/beanie/beanie.svc) in a browser to see the error message.

You might also have to disable the custom errors feature of IIS to see the real error message, instead of a generic one.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```